# How to create .exe from jar files in java?

Tags: java, jar, exe

We created `jar` file of our project.`Jar` file name is `stock.jar`,in `dist` folder: `lib` folder,one `stock.jar`,`stock.sqlite`.

Now we want to create `.exe` with database and `lib` folder jars.

Comment: Why creating an exe, which is system-dependent, when you can create a jar, which is portable ?

Comment: Jar file is portable sir.

Comment: I know that's exactly my point... jar is portable but exe isn't

Comment: I maintain a [list of JAR to EXE conversion tools, free and commercial](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/best-jar-to-exe-conversion-tools-free-commercial.html)

Answer (score 8):

Here are the List of option you have

1. [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/)
3. [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)
4. [JarToExe](http://www.jar2exe.com/)
5. [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)

   - [launcher and installer for Java applications - TUTORIAL](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html)
6. [JexePack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html)
7. [Executable Wrapper](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/executablewrapper.html#EXE)
8. [Jwrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/java-to-exe-free.html)

Comment: launch4j is not add databse.. this create .exe but without database

Comment: @Rajesh see this link https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy.html